# For multivariate Brownian motion $B$, why does $\operatorname{E}(f(B_T) \mid B_t = x)$ satisfy a generalized heat equation?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I came across the following assertion (without proof, so I assume this is well known in probability theory): If $B$ is a $d$-dimensional standard Brownian motion and $f \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable such that $f(B)$ is a martingale, then $g(t,x) = \operatorname{E} \left( f(B_T) \mid B_t = x \right)$ satisfies
$$
\int_0^T \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(t,x) \left( \frac{d}{dt}\varphi(t,x)  - \Delta_x \varphi(t,x) \right) dx dt = 0
$$
for all test functions $\varphi$, where $\Delta_x$ denotes the Laplacian with respect to $x$ and $T>0$ is some fixed real. Could anybody please provide a proof or a reference?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Presumably that is $=0$ (so $g$ is a weak solution to heat equation)?  And $T$ is presumably fixed rather than a stopping time?

Comment: @user10354138 yes, of course, thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected the question.

Comment: A very nice short, concise book on the subject (which reduces your question to a change of integral, as pointed out in Nate Eldredge's answer) is "Green, Brown and Probability" by Kai-Lai Chung.

Comment: @snar thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Markov property or independence of increments, the conditional distribution of $B_T$ given $B_t=x$ is $N(x, (T-t)I)$.  So you can write $g(t,x)$ as an integral of $f$ with respect to the standard normal density, use the fact that the normal density satisfies the heat equation, and then integrate by parts.

Comment: Thanks! I searched around a bit and actually this also follows as a special case of Feynman-Kac, doesn't it?

Comment: @n_flanders: Yes, a very special case, but I think some fact like this one really underlies Feynman-Kac in the first place.

Comment: got it, this is all completely new to me so I'll have to do a lot of reading to get some intuition